# JPA queries - using an argument's Entity Name as parameter to assosciated JPA query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Related questions don't seem to cover exactly what I'm trying to do.

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<FooEntity, Integer> {
    @Query("select child from BarEntity p inner join p.fooColumn child where p = :parent")
    Page<FooEntity> findBy(@Param("parent") HasFooInterface parent, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This is a query that returns pages of FooEntity where BarEntity is the parent in the relationship.

What I want, is for the query to be defined in a generic way. The `parent` object that's an instance of HasFooInterface will always be an entity with a relation to Foo (BarEntity in this example).

So where it says `@Query("select child from BarEntity p inner join p.fooColumn child where p = :parent")`

I want to be able to parameterize that "BarEntity" to be

`@Query("select child from _?parent.getClass.getSimpleName()?_ p inner join p.fooColumn child where p = :parent")`

What can I replace here to get the functionality I need?

Comment: @Query("select child from "+parent.getClass.getSimpleName()+" p inner join p.fooColumn child where p = :parent")

Comment: No, that wouldn't work as parent is not accessible inside the query annotation.